# Operation timed out error when running spring-boot:run

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, kotlin

I am trying to run through the [Spring Quickstart Guide](https://spring.io/quickstart).

I have the DemoApplication.kt file updated to

```
package com.example.demo

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
class DemoApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<DemoApplication>(*args)
}

@GetMapping("/hello")
fun hello(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") name: String?): String? {
    return String.format("Hello %s!", name)
}
```

When I run `./mvnw spring-boot:run` it times out with `Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out`.

Stack Trace

```
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:639)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:304)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:174)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:183)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:532)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:637)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:266)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:380)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:193)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1245)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1131)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:179)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1668)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1592)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.DefaultDownloader.downloadInternal(DefaultDownloader.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.DefaultDownloader.download(DefaultDownloader.java:93)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.Installer.createDist(Installer.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main(MavenWrapperMain.java:72)
```

Any idea what I need to do differently? Thanks.

Comment: Please post the stack trace

Comment: Added stack trace

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is a proxy issue now. But I don't know where to add the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

The Spring App you wrote wouldn't normally make an outbound connection that could fail - that was what was confusing about the original question.

Now that you have provided the stack trace it is clearer what is going on.

What's happening is that you are compiling and running the app using Maven and Maven needs some more artefacts for your application so it is automatically downloading them for you `org.apache.maven.wrapper.DefaultDownloader.download(....`

So if you have to use a proxy to reach the Internet, then you need to give these details to *Maven*.  Try this guide: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Comment: I tried adding a settings.xml where maven is installed, and I tried adding the proxy to the pom file. Neither fixed the problem. Do you know where I need to add the xml?

Comment: Look for a `.m2` folder in your Home Directory